# Release project with SNAPSHOT test dependency

Tags: maven, release, maven-release-plugin

I am using **snapshot dependency just for tests** in my project

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my-company</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-test-library</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I am aware about the risks of using `LATEST` but that's exactly what I want to achieve in tests. However, this test dependency **blocks release of production code** when I invoke `mvn release:prepare` with exception:

```
[INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
There are still some remaining snapshot dependencies.
...
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseFailureException: Can't release project due to non released dependencies :
    com.my-company:my-test-library:jar:LATEST:test
in project 'My Project'
```

My `dependencyManagement`:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
        <id>rep-releases</id>
        <name>Release Repo</name>
        <url>${url}</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
        <id>rep-snapshots</id>
        <name>Snapshots Repo</name>
        <url>${url}</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Why test code has anything to do with release procedure? How can I proceed with release and leave the dependency as it is?

Comment: could you share the `distributionManagement` details from the pom.xml as well

Comment: Never use such things like `LATEST` in a version...Furthermore if you rely on test code which is not released you can't reproduce your build. And that's the reason why release plugin complains...

Comment: @khmarbaise As I wrote, I am aware of all consequences of using LATEST and not having reproducible build. I'm just asking WHY release plugin complains about TEST code while trying to release PRODUCTION code.

Comment: @nullpointer `dependencyManagement` added

Comment: It's comprehensible that it complains: If test code is used that's still under development it isn't assured that the production code to be released is properly tested as intended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing is really against all rules and you should also be making a release for your test dependency first, then releasing and then switching the version of the project to a snapshot and restoring the test-scoped dependency to a snapshot.

If you really, really, really must do stupid things, then you can specify the [`-DignoreSnapshots=true`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#allowTimestampedSnapshots) option. However, this will ignore any `SNAPSHOT` dependencies defined in your `pom.xml` which is even worse.

You have been warned. Proceed at your own risk and may God have mercy!

Comment: Thanks, one part of my question is answered. But second still remains open - why release plugin checks test-scoped dependencies? Shouldn't it check just production code dependencies?

Comment: Because the whole point of creating a release is that you would have a fully reproducible state of your code at any given point in time in the future. If you have a `SNAPSHOT` of any kind and you rebuild the code in, say five months, then that test dependency may have changed and your tagged code might no longer work and that would definitely not be reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

if you aware of all consequences of using LATEST. you may use the command:

```
mvn release:prepare  -DignoreSnapshots=true
```

property `ignoreSnapshots=true`  to allow SNAPSHOT dependencies